# QGIS 3.6 menu bar missing

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, ubuntu, linux

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 with the XFCE interface and QGIS v3.6. When I start QGIS the menu bar at the top of the window is missing, and I can't find any way to bring it back. I found some solutions online that suggest modifying the QGIS2.conf file, but I don't have one of those.

Do any of you have ideas how to solve this? The main reason I use QGIS is to save quick previews of images, which is no longer possible without the menu bar!

(edit) Rostranimin suggests launching from the command line with the no configuration option, I had actually already tried this (but neglected to mention it). Doing so still results in no menu bar.
(edit2) To give more background info:
I was previously using Ubuntu 14.04 on this machine and whatever the default version of QGIS was for that distro (2.4?), then my company upgraded me to 18.04 with QGIS 3.6.
In 2.4 the menubar was visible, it hasn't been visible since the update. Unfortunately as this is a company-managed machine I don't have sudo access, so my options to change things are limited.

I have another machine (self-managed) that's running Mint 19 with QGIS 3.6, the menu bar appears fine there.

Comment: You can certainly launch QGIS using the command line on Windows, with an option for no configuration. I've not done this on linux. See the 'tip' box on this page: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#sec-customization (which specifies launching QGIS from the command line with the '--nocustomization' option specified).

Comment: I should have mentioned (and have now edited my post) that I had already tried that: No change.

Comment: @os1 - Maybe try the following in the Python Console in case it is hidden: `iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QMenuBar)[0].show()`

Comment: Just guessing/troubleshooting now and may not help at all - but try F11 (toggle full screen mode) and ctrl+shift+tab (toggle map only).

Comment: On Joseph's comment - you need ctrl+alt+p to get the python console if you have no menu...

Comment: @Joseph Thanks, unfortunately nothing happens when I run that command.

Comment: @Rostranimin Thanks to you too, that also doesn't have any effect - menu bar still missing.

Comment: OK - last question, and last suggestion... 1) Did you previously have the menu bar (and it now disappeared). Do you have any idea what prompted this? Or has it never been there on this machine/installation? 2) As a workaround... you might like to try running QGIS using the Flatpak version (from Flathub)? My home machine (Linux Mint) seems happy with this - although I've not used it much. See details at the bottom of this page: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html?highlight=installation

Comment: @Rostranimin Sorry, I should have written that in the original question. Have updated it now.